# RewriteRule in .htaccess not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently running Apache2 on my local machine, installed with the latest version of Ubuntu.

I am trying to get basic URL rewriting working by using the .htaccess file.

The file "http://localhost/page.php?=home" does exist, and the location "/doesnotexist/home" does not.

I would like to have the first page be loaded when the second is requested.

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/doesnotexist/(.*)$ /page.php?p=$1
```

My httpd.conf file looks like this:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so

<Directory /var/www>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Note that my httpd.conf file looks *exactly* like that, as it was empty before I edited it.

The result that I get is this:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /doesnotexist/home was not found on this server.
```

I have googled the ever living **** out of this problem, and I have never gotten anything other than the error above.

If anyone has any ideas, I would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For the benefit of others, I figured out the answer:

In the file "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default" there was the line:

```
AllowOverride None
```

Change this to:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: Note: that configuration option has been moved to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: I changed this under <Directory /var/www/> and now it's 500 Internal server error...

Comment: Worked for me. On Mac OS X (2021) you can find that option under `<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">` in httpd.conf  (which somehow is daunting when Mac OS X's Apache is layed out slightly differently to Linux (no `sites-enabled` dir)

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the contextual path prefix from your pattern when using mod_rewrite in a .htaccess file. In the case of the root directory, the path prefix is just `/`. So try this:

```
RewriteRule ^doesnotexist/(.*)$ /page.php?p=$1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but sorry, the behavior is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

If I place a .htaccess into /Library/WebServer/Documents and open "localhost/"; to test it, this works as expected. It just doesn't work in "~/Sites". I have tried this on Mac OS X Mavericks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} `!-f`
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} `!-d`
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please describe your code in 1-2 minimal sentences.