# Using .htaccess so a directory routes to a php file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a PHP system that handles the import of data (using HTTP POST requests from other systems). I am developing a SOAP web service, basically as a wrapper for the existing functionality.

Currently, the POST request that users send their CSV file looks like:

https://www.mysite.com.au/_pag/shop/ABC/?sec=import/orders&pag=new

I want to clean this up a bit and have a URL similar to https://www.mysite.com.au/api

This might sound open ended, but what are typical methods to achieve this *without* breaking existing functionality? Using `.htaccess` in the root directory?
The existing functionality will look at the URL so it knows where to look to include assets such as javascripts and css files.

I'm thinking something like this would work, but I am not entirely sure how to implement it:

- Create a new file (index2.php for example) and hardcode the `$_REQUEST` and `$_GET` variables as above.
- Use a `.htaccess` rule to basically route anything for /api to the index2.php.

Does the above sound correct? What type of `.htaccess` rule would so such a thing?

My .htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api$ phpinfo.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php

php_flag  display_errors                  on
php_flag  display_startup_errors          on
php_flag  file_uploads                    on
php_value error_reporting                 2047
php_value max_input_time                  60
php_value post_max_size                   8M
php_value upload_max_filesize             2M
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for URL rewriting. Your root .htaccess could have something like:

```
RewriteEngine On    #once
RewriteRule    ^products/([0-9]+)/?$    product.php?product_id=$1
```

This would "rewrite"/route requests to site.com/products/5 to site.com/product.php?product_id=5.

In your case:

```
RewriteRule ^api$ _pag/shop/ABC/?sec=import/orders&pag=new
```

I recommend reading up on this [here](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/). A bit chatty but in depth.

Comment: Thanks alot for that. Having trouble getting it working. I've created a simple `phpinfo.php` in the root directory and modified `.htaccess` to show RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^api$ phpinfo.php. When I access http://www.mysite.com/api, it defaults to my 404 error handler.

Comment: Can you double-check the filename and the corresponding entry in .htaccess?

Comment: Also - your apache virtual host configuration should include "AllowOverride All" for you to be able to use Rewrite rules in your .htaccess files. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194137/rewriterule-in-htaccess-not-working

Comment: Yep the filename is correct because if i rename the 404 document, I get a server error. I'll update my question with the file

Comment: Does the 404 error complain about /api not found or /phpinfo.php not found?

Comment: New question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452839/cant-get-htaccess-to-work-404-not-found