# Can't get .htaccess mod_rewrite rules to work - 404 Not Found

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to get a simple .htaccess rewrite rule to work, but I can't seem to work it out.

My .htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api$ phpinfo.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php

php_flag  display_errors                  on
php_flag  display_startup_errors          on
php_flag  file_uploads                    on
php_value error_reporting                 2047
php_value max_input_time                  60
php_value post_max_size                   8M
php_value upload_max_filesize             2M
```

When I access `/api`, I get a 404 error saying that `/api` can't be found.

My apache conf file looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  NameVirtualHost 10.104.17.3:443
  <VirtualHost 10.104.17.3:443>
    ServerName orddev.foo.com.au
    DocumentRoot /var/www/orddev.foo.com.au___443/html
    <Directory />
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/var/www/orddev.foo.com.au___443/html">
      Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews IncludesNOEXEC
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
      php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/var/www/orders.foo.com.au___443/resources/_tmp/upload/"
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
      RewriteRule .* - [F]
    </IfModule>
    ErrorLog  logs/orddev.foo.com.au___443/ssl_error.log
    CustomLog logs/orddev.foo.com.au___443/ssl_access.log combinedio
    CustomLog logs/orddev.foo.com.au___443/ssl_request.log ssl
    LogLevel warn
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:+SHA1:+MD5:!SSLv2
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/orddev.foo.com.au.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/orddev.foo.com.au.key
    <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php|php3?)$">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Files>
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
      nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
      downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
I know the .htaccess is being read as if I change the 404 document, I get an error about the 404 document not being setup properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your apache isn't loading mod_rewrite.

Locate your httpd.conf and search for "rewrite_module".

If that line begins with a # (making it a comment), remove the # and restart apache.

In mine, the line is:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

...but YMMV.

Comment: It's not commented :(. LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so. I've verified that file exists as well. `phpinfo()` shows `mod_rewrite` under loaded modules.

Comment: Hmm. I just had the rule to `RewriteRule ^phpinfo.php$ index.php` and it loaded `index.php`, but if I change it to RewriteRule `^api$ index.php` and access `https://foo.bar.com.au/api`, no go.

Comment: very strange. Try `RewriteRule ^api.php$ index.php`?

Comment: I got it to work by adding a slash! `RewriteRule ^api.php/$ index.php`

Comment: Huh. Is your browser adding it (the slash) to the request? In any case, try `RewriteRule ^api.?$ destination.php`. This will match api and an optional single character, so apia, api0, api/ should work.

Comment: and for the record, what OS and apache version are you using?

Comment: Apache is 2.2 running on Centos 5.8 final. I was thinking the browser might be doing that. I use Firefox, I tried IE and it did the same thing. It looks like the browser is adding a slash though. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 5):

I had a working .htaccess file that I switched over to another server. It was working fine before and stopped working after the switch. I solved the problem by configuring the httpd.conf file.

SSH onto your server and open the httpd.conf file for editing:

```
cd /etc/httpd/conf
sudo nano httpd.conf
```

find the "Directory" tag. Should look like this->

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
```

Replace **AllowOverride None** with

```
AllowOverride All
```

Restart

```
sudo service httpd restart
```