# Creating dynamic file in php (not the title)

Tags: php

What I want to do:

Create dynamic php file for each product. What I'm currently doing is, if a person clicks on a products , it opens in one single file with some data i.e. `www.example.com/showproduct.php?ref=1085`. Here 1085 is a productid & thus it shows the content from DB for the particular id.

Is it possible to show the URL as `www.example.com/google-nexus-5-16gb-black.php`, where this data comes from DB content?

I don't want to create a page for each product, I think that would be a waste. Is there any solution? You can see even on `stackoverflow` how it shows the URL for each question.

**EDIT**

I've used following code in `.htaccess` file, however it's not rewriting the URL.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ref/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ showproduct.php?ref=$1 [NC]
```

Any problem with this? And my I will try connecting to DB & get the file name once I know how this works.

Comment: Yes, it is possible with `.htaccess`.

Comment: `.htaccess` or `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a **unique** alias field for each product record in your DB, and then you can use `mod_rewrite` to map `www.example.com/YOUR-ALIAS` to `www.example.com/showproduct.php?alias=YOUR-ALIAS`. This will give your the desired *friendly URL* effect.

#### Update

In your case it appears that you merely want to map `google-nexus-5-16gb-black.php` to `showproduct.php?ref=1085`, creating a additional alias field may be overkilled. In this case, you may setup a single rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^google-nexus-5-16gb-black.php$  /showproduct.php?ref=1085 [L]
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it should, though. (RewriteRule works fine on my server, I've https rewriterules that work fine)

Comment: The rewrite rule above works well on my server ([demo1](http://w3lab.cc/showproduct.php?ref=1085), [demo2](http://w3lab.cc/google-nexus-5-16gb-black.php), [demo3](http://w3lab.cc/showproduct.php?ref=1)). If it doesn't work on yours it probably means some configuration is needed.

Comment: I think you haven't understood me clearly. There is no such file `google-nexus-5-16gb-black.php`, I only want to show `showproduct.php?ref=1085` as `google-nexus-5-16gb-black.php`.

Comment: In my server, the file `google-nexus-5-16gb-black.php` does not exist. We are mapping the url `www.example.com/google-nexus-5-16gb-black.php` to the content at `www.example.com/showproduct.php?ref=1085`, isn't this what you are trying to do?

Comment: I thought, it's file on your server, sorry, my mistake. That's exactly I want to do, somehow it's not working on my server, the exact same code.

Comment: Perhaps youneed to config your apache server, do you get an error 404 when accessing `google-nexus-5-16gb-black.php`? If so, please take a look at this post (both of the answers): [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452839/cant-get-htaccess-mod-rewrite-rules-to-work-404-not-found)

Comment: No I do not get that error, it redirects to `showproduct.php`

Comment: Please make sure you have done the following: (1) Create a `.htaccess` file consists of the `mod_write` rules above, (2) Place both the `.htaccess` and `showproduct.php` files at the root of your server.

Comment: This is already done, I have a few https rules within that file & those work fine.

Comment: Will our rule got override by the existing rules (because of the ordering perhaps)? It will be great if you can test with a fresh `.htaccess` file (on a *non-productive* server).

Comment: Sure, was thinking to do the same.

Comment: Okay so here is the case, for the both the URLs, it remains same. For `showproduct`, it remains `showproduct` & for `google-nexus`, it remains `google-nexus` (with a fresh .htaccess)

Comment: No, not the way I want, I want `showproduct` URL to show `google-nexus` only, not its own.

Comment: I am a bit confused...So you to **redirect** `google-nexus` to `showproduct?ref=ref=1085`? You don't want the address bar in your browser to show something like `www.example.com/google-nexus` right?

Comment: Let me clear it out then. My actual URL is `www.example.com?showproduct.php?ref=100`, I want to show this URL as `www.example.com/google-nexus-5-black.php`. Got it?

Comment: In your previous comment, you mentioned you got `google-nexus` when you access the url corresponds to `google-nexus`. In my server, it gives you the desired result (i.e. it maps to the content of showproduct.php), but what actually happens in your case? Do you get a 404 error or does there exist a page called `google-nexus.php`?

Comment: No, I do not get a 404 error. What happens is, when I open `www.example.com?showproduct.php?ref=100`, it shows as this only(no redirect to google-nexus). When I open this url `www.example.com/google-nexus-5-black.php`, it shows as this only.

Comment: What I want is no matter what URL you open, I want to show `www.example.com/google-nexus-5-black.php`. (There is no such file on a server)

Comment: Do you have some file called `google-nexus-5-black.php` on your server? If so, it is not surprise that you are not getting error 404. I highly suspect `mod_write` is NOT working as desired on your server, please make sure you have implemented the configuration in both answers in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452839/cant-get-htaccess-mod-rewrite-rules-to-work-404-not-found).

Comment: No buddy, I do not have `google-nexus-5-black.php` file on my server. And I'm not getting 404 error. May be it's not working desirably, but it's definitely working, all that I can say.

Comment: I have no idea how this would happen, I suggest you to investigate your server access log to confirm `google-nexus-5-16gb-black.php` is truly accessible (200 response). You should be able to get the desired result as demonstrated by my server if you have implemented the above `mod_rewrite` rule. Good luck to you and hopefully you can solve this problem sure. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this help, I will surely look into why such thing happens. :)

Answer (score 0):

### .htaccess

URL rewriting file. Redirecting original URL www.example.com/showproduct.php?ref=1085 to www.example.com/google-nexus-5-16gb-black.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).php$ showproduct.php?ref=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).php/$ showproduct.php?ref=$1
```

You can read more about [Basic URL Rewrite](http://phpcreating.blogspot.com/2010/02/url-rewriting.html)

```
<?php
    include('db.php'); // Connection to your database
    if($_GET['ref'])
    {
        $url=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ref']);
        $sql=mysql_query("select title from table where ref='$url'");
        $count=mysql_num_rows($sql);
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
        $title=$row['title'];
    }
?>
```

Probably this [link](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/04/seo-friendly-urls-with-php.html) will help you to do what you are looking for

Comment: Your code will open every single page to showproduct.php file

Comment: @ShanilSoni you can do that for all your pages which is showing the product info. If you wanted to do that