# htaccess rewrite file with no extention not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

This rule does not work. Why?

```
RewriteRule ^/events_page/?$ events_page.php [L]
```

Its basically just saying to point the page with no extension to the .php file.

If the catch part was not equal to the file name it would work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please make `mod_rewrite` is working on your server. If it doesn't, you may take a look at this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452839/cant-get-htaccess-mod-rewrite-rules-to-work-404-not-found) for reference. You may try the following `mod_rewrite` rules:

Following rule will map `www.example.com/events_page/` to `www.example.com/events_page.php`

```
RewriteRule ^events_page?$ events_page.php [L]<br />
```

Following rule will map `www.example.com/events_page/?` to `www.example.com/events_page.php`

```
RewriteRule ^events_page/?$ events_page.php [L]
```

Following rule will map `www.example.com/events_page/WHATEVER_FOLLOWS` to `www.example.com/events_page.php`

```
RewriteRule ^events_page/(.*)?$ events_page.php [L]
```